# Uniswap V3 reverts execution on 'quoteExactInputSingle' function

Tags: uniswap, python, uniswapv3

I am working on goerli testnet with uniswap and trying to get token price with fee included. In order to accomplish I call `uniswap.get_price_input` python uniswap library function. It runs perfectly with Uniswap V2 but it doesn't take fees into account. Hence I switched towards V3. But it fails while calling for `quoteExactInputSingle`.
Here is my code:

```
token_addr = Web3.to_checksum_address("0xfad6367e97217cc51b4cd838cc086831f81d38c2") # goerli USDT
price = api.get_price_input(uniswap.constants.ETH_ADDRESS, token_addr, 1)
```

Can someone, please, help me to figure this out?